# Out Of Memory generating emails via excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have some VBA code that I run from within excel that generates emails and attaches an excel file to the email, based on the subjects name. The macro seems to run fine for 101 emails, then fails, almost 100% of the time. Each attachment is 15kb, and the total amount of emails to create will vary, but for testing I have 128 total.

The actual email composition is the body of an email, with the default signature attached, subject is static and to is variable.

I can't identify any modifications required to the code, I'm dropping to OAMail Item every iteration, so I'm somewhat as a loss (this is the standard issue that seemingly goes wrong).

Code below:

```
Sub Generate_Emails()

    Dim OApp As Object
    Dim OMail As Object
    Dim signature As String
    Dim emailbody As String
    Dim ET As Worksheet
    Dim Sum_WS As Worksheet
    Dim EL As Worksheet
    Dim CS As Worksheet

    Set ET = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EmailTemplate")
    Set Sum_WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set EL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EmailList")
    Set CS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ControlSheet")
    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Check if emails can be generated
    If CS.Range("F2") = "No" Then
        MsgBox "Cannot generate files until Files have been generated", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(EL.Range("A:A"))
        body = ET.Range("A1")

        'Go through each email in email list
        For j = 2 To i
            'Create email object
            Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            'Get default signature
            With OMail
                .GetInspector
            End With
            'Allocate signature and body
            signature = OMail.HTMLBody
            'Create the whole email and add attachment
            With OMail
                .To = EL.Cells(j, 2)
                .Subject = "SOx RemTP Audit " & Sum_WS.Range("C2")
                .HTMLBody = body & vbNewLine & signature
                .Attachments.Add Sum_WS.Range("B2") & "\SOx RemTP Audit " & Sum_WS.Range("C2") & " - " & EL.Cells(j, 1) & ".xlsx"
                .Save
            End With

            Application.StatusBar = "Generating Email " & j & " of " & i
            DoEvents

            Set OMail = Nothing
        Next j
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If
    Set OApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "All emails placed into Outlook draft folder", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - try closing the object after saving

Comment: Assuming you mean:

            With OMail
                .To = EL.Cells(j, 2)
                .Subject = EmailSubject
                .HTMLBody = body & vbNewLine & signature
                .Attachments.Add AttachmentsFolder & EL.Cells(j, 1) & ".xlsx"
                .Save
                Set OMail = Nothing
            End With

Then yes, but it made zero difference

Comment: No, I was thinking of OMail.Close 0

Comment: Adding OMail.Close after the save makes it crop up "Argument Not Optional"

Comment: That's why I put a 0 after. This means olSave - but if you have not added an Outlook reference, a zero will do.

Comment: Ah I see, that did the job. Code will now run successfully, and also seems to work far more. Stands to reason that having 100+ emails "open" at the same time would cause a memory fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes: Your code looks fine but use `Option Explicit`.

See my comments in the code starting with `'##` …

```
Option Explicit '## force proper variable declare to avoid typos and issues

Public Sub Generate_Emails()
    Dim OApp As Object
    Dim OMail As Object
    Dim signature As String
    Dim emailbody As String
    Dim ET As Worksheet
    Dim Sum_WS As Worksheet
    Dim EL As Worksheet
    Dim CS As Worksheet

    Set ET = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EmailTemplate")
    Set Sum_WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set EL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EmailList")
    Set CS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ControlSheet")
    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Check if emails can be generated
    If CS.Range("F2") = "No" Then
        MsgBox "Cannot generate files until Files have been generated", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim i As Long '## dim i
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(EL.Range("A:A"))
        emailbody = ET.Range("A1")

        'Go through each email in email list
        Dim j As Long '## dim j
        For j = 2 To i
            'Create email object
            Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            'Get default signature
            With OMail '## tidied up your with block (one is enough)
                .GetInspector

                'Allocate signature and body
                signature = .HTMLBody

                'Create the whole email and add attachment
                .To = EL.Cells(j, 2)
                .Subject = "SOx RemTP Audit " & Sum_WS.Range("C2")
                .HTMLBody = emailbody & vbNewLine & signature
                .Attachments.Add Sum_WS.Range("B2") & "\SOx RemTP Audit " & Sum_WS.Range("C2") & " - " & EL.Cells(j, 1) & ".xlsx"
                .Save
                .Close 0 '## close the mail to not leave it open (this might be the issue)
                         '0=olSave; 1=olDiscard; 2=olPromptForSave
            End With

            Application.StatusBar = "Generating Email " & j & " of " & i
            DoEvents

            'Set OMail = Nothing '## not needed
        Next j
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If
    'Set OApp = Nothing '## not needed

    MsgBox "All emails placed into Outlook draft folder", vbInformation
End Sub
```

`Set Something = Nothing` is almost not needed because VBA does this automatically on `End Sub`.

Comment: Option explicit is added to the workbook as a whole, I was under the impression it cascaded down. As for adding .close, I'm adding that in and getting an error "Argument not optional". Isolated to it being the ".close"

Comment: I've resolved the issue by adding ".close 0" instead of just ".close". Code now runs perfectly and efficiently. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by adding ".close 0" to the With statement.

Original loop:

```
'Go through each email in email list
        For j = 2 To i
            'Create email object
            Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            'Get default signature
            With OMail
                .GetInspector
            End With
            'Allocate signature and body
            signature = OMail.HTMLBody
            'Create the whole email and add attachment
            With OMail
                .To = EL.Cells(j, 2)
                .Subject = "SOx RemTP Audit " & Sum_WS.Range("C2")
                .HTMLBody = body & vbNewLine & signature
                .Attachments.Add Sum_WS.Range("B2") & "\SOx RemTP Audit " & Sum_WS.Range("C2") & " - " & EL.Cells(j, 1) & ".xlsx"
                .Save
            End With

            Application.StatusBar = "Generating Email " & j & " of " & i
            DoEvents

            Set OMail = Nothing
        Next j
```

Amended loop, after adding .close 0 and merging the with:

```
    'Go through each email in email list
    For j = 2 To i
        'Create email object
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
        'Get default signature
        With OMail
            .GetInspector
            'Allocate signature
            signature = OMail.HTMLBody
            'Create the whole email and add attachment
            .To = EL.Cells(j, 2)
            .Subject = emailsubject
            .HTMLBody = emailbody & vbNewLine & signature
            .Attachments.Add attachmentsfolder & EL.Cells(j, 1) & ".xlsx"
            .Save
            .Close 0
        End With


        Application.StatusBar = "Generating Email " & j & " of " & i
        DoEvents

        Set OMail = Nothing
    Next j
```

Thanks to Peh and Sam for providing resolution